# What's the strange double underscored attribute (__attribute__) in Python?

Tags: python

I see some strange but useful double underscored attribute in Python, such as:

```
__module__
__init__
__str__
__class__
__repr__
...
```

They seem to be some special attributes. What's the canonical name for them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are called **Special Methods**.

Python is a **Duck Typed** Language and many of the
user-facing features of the language are implemented
in "protocols" implemented by these special methods.

See: http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/specialnames.html

As an **Example**:

To mimic comparison of arbitrary objects you implement the following two methods in your class:

- `__lt__`
- `__eq__`

Comment: +1 for "Duck Typed", very informative! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Per ["Naming conventions" section of **PEP-8**](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or
>   attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`,
>   `__import__` or `__file__`. Never invent such names; only use them as
>   documented.

Comment: Man that PEP must be old! I think 50% of Pythonistas call them special methods the other other 50% magic methods :)

Comment: Yup 13 years old this year! +1 on the "convention" used.

Comment: @JamesMills: right, the original is old, but it's kept up to date. `Last modified Fri, 01 Nov 2013.`